# Condition ici=ic on a topological space is equivalent to if each dense set has dense interior in the space.

Tags: general-topology

I am required to prove the following: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.Then each dense set has dense interior iff $ici=ic$ holds where $i$ is the interior operator and $c$ is the closure operator.

Firstly suppose $ici=ic$ holds and for $A \subseteq X $ which is dense in $X$ that is $c(A)=X$,then we show that $i(A)$ is also dense in $X$ that is $ci(A)=X$.This part follows directly.

Conversely,we suppose each dense set has dense interior.We show that $ici=ic$ holds.

Suppose $A\subseteq X$ which is dense in $X$ that is $c(A)=X$ then by hypothesis $ci(A)=X$
Therefore $ici=ic$ holds for all subsets dense in the space.But How will I proceed to prove it in general for any arbitrary subset of space?Can someone please help me how to go about the proof?

Comment: Your objection to my claim about the interior of $A\cup(X\setminus c(A))$ is well taken. I’ve obviously not been thinking clearly about this problem, so for now I’m simply deleting my answer. I’ll try to come back to it a bit later with a clearer head.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott hoping for an early reply from your side soon.